# Node.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TokenType')

Tags: javascript, node.js, powerbi

I have a simple node.js application that have basic login page and for `user1` it embed private power bi report. everything working as expected except when `user1` actually login, a blank page shown with the following error in the console:

```
dashboard:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TokenType')
    at HTMLDocument.
```

Where the error is refer to this in my `dashboard.ejs`:

```
tokenType: powerbi.models.TokenType.Embed,
```

The server side, has this `server.js`:

```
...
app.get('/dashboard', async (req, res) => {
    const user = req.session.user;

    if (user === 'user1') {
        try {
            const accessToken = [Hidden]
            console.log(`\n\n your token is >>>\n  ${accessToken} \n\n`);
    
            const apiUrl = `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/[Hidden]/reports/${encodeURIComponent('[Hidden]')}/GenerateToken`;
            console.log(`your api url is >>>  ${apiUrl} \n\n`);

            const apiResponse = await axios.post(apiUrl, {
                accessLevel: 'view'
            }, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
                }
            });
            console.log(`your response is >>>  ${apiResponse} \n\n`);

            const embedToken = apiResponse.data.token;
            console.log(`your embed token is  ${embedToken} \n\n`);
            res.render('dashboard', { embedURL: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=[Hidden]&autoAuth=true&ctid=[Hidden]', embedToken });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error generating Power BI embed token:', error);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    } else if (user === 'user2') {
        res.render('dashboard', { welcomeMessage: 'Welcome, User 2!' });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

And my client side `dashboard.ejs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <script src="/powerbi.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <% if (embedURL && embedToken) { %>
        <div id="reportContainer" style="height: 600px;"></div>
        <script>
            // Make sure powerbi object is available before using it
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                var embedConfiguration = {
                    type: 'report',
                    id: '<%= embedURL %>',
                    embedUrl: '<%= embedURL %>',
                    tokenType: powerbi.models.TokenType.Embed, // Use powerbi.models.TokenType.Embed
                    accessToken: '<%= embedToken %>',
                    settings: {
                        filterPaneEnabled: false,
                        navContentPaneEnabled: false
                    }
                };

                // Embed the report
                var reportContainer = document.getElementById('reportContainer');
                var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, embedConfiguration);
            });
        </script>
    <% } else if (welcomeMessage) { %>
        <h2><%= welcomeMessage %></h2>
    <% } %>
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
...
```

Update:

In case of replacing `tokenType: powerbi.models.TokenType.Embed` by `tokenType: window["powerbi-client"].models.TokenType.Embed` the following exception thrown:

```
powerbi.js:7801 Uncaught Error: Embed URL is invalid for this scenario. Please use Power BI REST APIs to get the valid URL
    at Report.Embed (powerbi.js:7801:19)
    at new Report (powerbi.js:9487:24)
    at __webpack_modules__../src/service.ts.Service.createEmbedComponent (powerbi.js:11288:20)
    at __webpack_modules__../src/service.ts.Service.embedNew (powerbi.js:11268:30)
    at __webpack_modules__../src/service.ts.Service.embedInternal (powerbi.js:11226:30)
    at __webpack_modules__../src/service.ts.Service.embed (powerbi.js:11189:21)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (dashboard:30:38)
```

And in case replacing it by `models.TokenType.Embed`, I get the following error:

```
dashboard:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: models is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (dashboard:20:33)
```

Comment: Can you share `powerbi.js`?

Comment: It is available here: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/tree/master/dist

Comment: In your `dashboard.ejs`, try replacing `tokenType: powerbi.models.TokenType.Embed` to `tokenType: window["powerbi-client"].models.TokenType.Embed` or to just `models.TokenType.Embed`.

Comment: @SamNseir I will put the updates in the question.

Comment: Also, [`index.js`](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/master/NodeJS/Embed%20for%20your%20customers/AppOwnsData/public/js/index.js) doesn't seem to be used in your setup.

Comment: You need to re-visit your implementation. Changing to `window["powerbi-client"].models.TokenType.Embed` has fixed the issue, and now you are onto the next new issue.

Comment: @SamNseir you are correct. please submit your answer to accept as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `dashboard.ejs`, try replacing

```js
tokenType: powerbi.models.TokenType.Embed
```

to

```js
tokenType: window["powerbi-client"].models.TokenType.Embed
```

I suspect that will resolve the `TokenType` error. If it does, then you will need to re-visit your implementation. Have a look at [`index.js`](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/master/NodeJS/Embed%20for%20your%20customers/AppOwnsData/public/js/index.js) which seems to be missing, or parts of it are missing in your `server.js`.